# Do firebase dynamic links work with PWA applications?

Tags: firebase, firebase-dynamic-links

Firebase dynamic link documentation does not show Web as a category it supports but I wanted to know if there is any hack out there where can get it to work for PWA applications? the google analytics tracking for firebase is a powerful feature, especially for dynamic links.

Comment: I have a similar question, will dynamic links also work as deep link into PWA?

Answer (score 0):

Even though there is no specific API for this, since Dynamic Links are just URLs, you can indeed use then within a web app.

For example, we used them in the [PWA for the Firebase Summit in 2018](https://firebase.events/#/next/a) to track click-throughs to the additional information for each session.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having issues with your PWA not running correctly in Facebooks (insert expletive) Mobile Browser.  Using dynamic links will force it out to the regular browser)

Do not use a custom domain, use the https://YOURDOMAIN.page.link

and DO NOT skip the preview page!